# Search box value is replaced with page number selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, elasticsearch

I am trying to make a search engine using elasticsearch and PHP. I am using AJAX for live data search. It was working fine until I applied pagination. When I applied pagination, my search query was replaced with the page number. i.e. input in the search box was replaced with page number and according documents where retrieved.
Here is my code in index.php file:

```
<div class="container">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">Search for any course</h2><br />
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
     <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search here..." class="form-control" />

     <br>
    </div>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div id="result"></div>
  </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch_nptel.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#result').html(data);
   }
  });
 }

 $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){  
    var page = $(this).attr("id"); 
    load_data(page);  
  });

 $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search != "")
  {
   load_data(search);
  }
  else
  {
   load_data();
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

And here the code in fetch.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(['127.0.0.1:9200'])->build();

$record_per_page = 10;
$page='';
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["page"]))  
{  
    $page = $_POST["page"];  
}  
else  
{  
    $page = 1;  
}  
$start_from = ($page - 1)*$record_per_page;  

if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $link='';
 $search = $_POST["query"];
 $query = $client->search([
    'body' => [
      'query' => [
        'bool' => [
          'must' => [
            'multi_match' => [
              'fields' => ['title','University','Professor','description'],
              'query' => $search
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ],

      'from' => 0,
      'size' => 350
    ]
  ]);

 $n = count($query['hits']['hits']);

 $query = $client->search([
    'body' => [
      'query' => [
        'bool' => [
          'must' => [
            'multi_match' => [
              'fields' => ['title','University','Professor','description'],
              'query' => $search
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ],

      'from' => $start_from,
      'size' => $record_per_page
    ]
  ]);

  if($query['hits']['total']>=1){
    $results = $query['hits']['hits'];
  }

}

if(isset($results))
{
 $output .= '
  <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: -10px;">Search results for "<b>'.$search.'</b>"</div>
  <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: -10px;">Found '.$n.' results</div>
 ';

 /*This foreach loop is just printing output variable, you may ignore this loop*/

 foreach($results as $r)
 {

  if(isset($r["_source"]["link"])){
  $link = $r["_source"]["link"];
  $output .='
    <div class="card card-1">
    <div id="sticky_header" class="title_header">
      <div class="title"><a class="title_link" href="' . $link . '">'.$r["_source"]["title"].'</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a href="' . $link . '">'.$r["_source"]["link"].'</a></div>
      <hr style="margin-top: 10px;">
    </div>
    <div class="description" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><b>Description:</b></div>
    <div>'.$r["_source"]["description"].'</div>
    </div>
    <hr style="margin-top: -5px;">
    <div class="div_university">
      <div class="professor" style="font-size: 15px; margin-top: -10px;  margin-bottom: 5px;"><b>Guided '.$r["_source"]["Professor"].'</b></div>
      <div class="university" style="font-size: 15px; margin-top: -5px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><b>Offered By: </b><em style="font-size: 15px;">'.$r["_source"]["University"].'</em></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  ';
  }

 }

 $total_pages = ceil($n/$record_per_page);  
 for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++)  
 {  
      $output .= '<span class="pagination_link" style="cursor:pointer; padding:6px; border:1px solid #ccc;" id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</span>';  
 }  
$output .= '</div><br /><br />';
 echo $output;
}
else
{
 echo 'No data found';
}
?>
```

I can see that in my index.php, my query value of load_data() function is replaced with the page number, that is why it is taking page number as input value.
So where am I making mistake?
I would highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling load_data with the page number in Javascript : load_data(page)
You need to add an extra parameter I think to your load_data.

```js
function load_data(query, page = 0)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch_nptel.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query, page: page},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#result').html(data);
   }
  });
```

and in click handler, pass both paremeters

```js
$(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){  
    var page = $(this).attr("id"); 
    var search = $('#search_text')
    load_data(search, page);  
  });
```

And finally, you should update your PHP code also.

Comment: thank you @Gillespie59...that helped. But after that caught another error:

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"numHits must be > 0; please use TotalHitCountCollector if you just need the total hit count"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"kr_v1","node":"ejVIcMUWSImolzvQXFurpA","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"numHits must be > 0; please use TotalHitCountCollector if you just need the total hit count"}}]},"status":400}

Comment: It is due to the query I am executing.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: yes, thank you so much @Gillespie59. As you said I had to pass the page number and my query to the load_data file and changed the php code a little bit and it worked. sorry, my laptop caught some problems and I had to send it to be repaired, so could not reply. Once again thank you.